# How to select specific variables ending with M1,M2 and M3 in SAS using Proc-sql?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a big data which contains 400+ Variables in SASUniversity Edition.Now,i want to select only those variables which ends with M1,M2 and M3.How can i do it using proc-Sql.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata table `DICTIONARY.COLUMNS` can be queried to select variable names of a data set`into` a macro variable that can be subsequently used in the `select` clause of a query against the data set.

`Proc CONTENTS` can also be used to obtain meta data, and thus variable names, of a data set.

A series of expressions `OR`d together, or a Perl regular expression can be used to select the `M` variable names.

SQL:

```
* suppose big data is a data set named PERM_LIB.SURVEY_RESULTS;

proc sql noprint;
  select name 
  into :varnamelist separated by ','
  from dictionary.columns  
  where libname = 'PERM_LIB' 
    and memname = 'SURVEY_RESULTS'
    and ( name like '%M1'
       or name like '%M2'
       or name like '%M3'
        )
  ;

  create table WORK.M_and_M_and_M as
  select id, &varnamelist
  from PERM_LIB.SURVEY_RESULTS
  ;
```

Contents:

```
data work.have;
  do id = 1 to 10;
    array v 
      x1-x10
      y1-y10
      z1-z10
      abcm1-abcm10
      defm1-defm20
    ;
    output;
  end;

proc contents noprint data=work.have out=havemeta;
run;    

%let varnamelist=;

proc sql noprint;
  select name into :varnamelist separated by ','
  from havemeta
  where prxmatch ('/(?i)M(1|2|3)[ ]*$/', name)
  ;

  create table work.have_M123s as 
  select id, &varnamelist from work.have
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlow, be sure to mark answers to your questions and upvote answers you find helpful.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers